# Affecting several elements on :Hover

Tags: javascript, css

I want the **.fa-sliders-h:hover** to happen when i hover the parent div **.r1c1:hover** without the parent without the parent div being affected by the red color and the 180deg.

Parent div

```
.r1c1:hover {
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
```

Icon inside in the Parent div

```
.fa-sliders-h:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);     /* Chrome and other webkit browsers */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);        /* FF */
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);          /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);         /* IE9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);             /* W3C compliant browsers */
    cursor: pointer;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
```

is this possible to perform?

Comment: `.r1c1:hover .fa-sliders-h {}`?

Comment: You learn something new everyday, thank you.